# Wide_deep classifier model, need to predict probability value, not only "best guess"

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I did build, owing a lot to the help I got on SO, a binary classifier basing on the the wide-and-deep Tensorflow tutorial ([here is its "Main" file this question is referring to](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py)), used in "wide" only mode.

The function I use to extract the classification guess is:

```
  pred_iter = model.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(FLAGS.test_data, 1, False, 1))   for pred in pred_iter:
    print(pred['classes'])
```

It works great in classifying but the classification is returned just as a `0` or a `1`, thus lacking the probabilistic aspect.

**I would like to get the classification expressed as a number between 0 and 1, in order to know "how sure" the net is of it's guesses.**

The [introduction itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py) says that

> We will train a logistic regression model, and given an individual's
>   information our model will output a number between 0 and 1, which can
>   be interpreted as the probability [...]

but I cannot manage to get such probabilistic aspect of the prediction.

I have tried to use the **prob_a** function listed in many answers but it proably refers to older version of `TF`, so no luck with it.

How can I effectivevly get the classification as a probablity and not as a "one shot"?

Any help is appreciated.

I am using TF 1.8 on Python 3.5, OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier) instances return a dictionary of values you can use. You're only using `pred[ 'classes' ]` in your code but you also have the probability values are in `pred[ 'probabilities' ]`. You can also just

```py
print( pred )
```

which will output something similar to this (with dummy data):

> {'logits': array([1.4264423], dtype=float32),
>   'logistic': array([0.80634636], dtype=float32),
>   'probabilities': array([0.19365363, 0.80634636], dtype=float32),
>   'class_ids': array([1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier)),
>   'classes': array([b'1'], dtype=object) }

so you can see you also have access to the `logits` and `class_ids`.

The probability of class 1 is the second value in `pred[ 'probabilities' ]`, which is what you want to use as I understand.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I have been looking for everywhere!
May you link me the relevant documentation to better understand also the other values returned?

Comment: Sure, happy to help! I don't know if there is a detailed description anywhere. I couldn't find one. That's why I used (and suggested) simply printing the result to see what's there.